# Checking corrupted file

Tags: pdftex, compiling, compilation-error

How do I check if my tex file is corrupted or not?

Texstudio was taking too much time to compile (more than 5 minutes). Then I stopped compilation and again started compiling. But it was same like before. Then I tried to open the pdf from the folder where the file is kept. It is now showing that `There was an error opening this document. This file is already open or in use by another application`. But the file is not open anywhere.

I next copied the whole coding and created a new file and pasted the codes there (and also copied and pasted a part of the whole document). It is same in those two files also.

**P.S: Sometimes before I unchecked `Internal PDF viewer -> Auto-recompile document on changes`.**

Currently I cut all the document and compiled just commands together with \begin{document}...\end{document}.. now it stops compiling. But in the right side where I see the pdf, there is a note: **'....pdf does not look like a valid pdf document. Either the file is corrupt or it is in the process of creation. Retrying every two seconds.'**

Comment: if you have to kill the compilation then something is certainly wrong.

Comment: what was the other option? The compilation is not stopping. What do I do now?

Comment: try to find out why it doesn't stop. Move \end{document} to an earlier point.

Comment: i did it taking 3-4 lines of my document. but same thing happening there also.

Comment: I am getting an error in the log file :`File ended while scanning use of \@writefile. \begin{document}`

Comment: But I don't know whether it's from last successful compilation or a new one. I have checked if there is any unended environment. But there is no such one.

Comment: delete the aux-file and try again.

Comment: did it. no positive result.

Comment: For us to be able to troubleshoot, you need to provide a lot more details. A TeX file that demonstrates the problem, the version of TeX you are running, perhaps the log file. There is pretty much nothing to go on right now based on the info you provided.

Comment: I don't know what's happening with this file. It behaves like a ghost. Sometime the pdf panel shows content, sometimes not. Sometimes the .pdf gets damaged, sometimes working

Comment: Sorry if I bother you after so much time, but did you find a solution? Because I am in your same situation and I don't know what to do

Comment: @TommasoSabbadini Yes the problem is solved. But I don't remember how I was able to solve it. As far as I can remember I reinstalled the file and cleaned the RAM. My system was running very slow at that time due to my system configuration like RAM